# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.app-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios8, xcode6

Error:

> target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.app-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

This may be not so hard to fix. However, this is Apple's new iOS8 extensibility feature and my app is supposed to run on iOS7 as well. I've created the extension using XCode6 beta but now I can't run my app on the device with iOS7 on it.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of things including opening the project.pbxproj file. Also cleaning the project was failing too! Which got me worried. I was getting this error on XCode 5 actually and we haven't fully switched to XCode6 because it is still a beta. However, when I opened the project in XCode6, I don't see the error and can still compile and run on iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

I believe after adding a new iOS8 feature such as a new Share Extension, project cannot be compiled and run using the old XCode5. I was trying to run on XCode5 because we're going to release soon and XCode6 is still a beta. Releasing using beta software is never a good idea.

I've noticed some of the code I've written wouldn't also compile in XCode5 and I've gotten around it using ifdef blocks such as:

```
#define iOSVersion ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
#ifdef iOSVersion
  NSExtensionContext *myExtensionContext = self.extensionContext;
  NSArray *inputItems = myExtensionContext.inputItems;
#endif
}
```

But it is better to continue to run the project on XCode6 for the Extensibility features as at this point I'm not sure how to get rid of the error using XCode5.